# User input produces blank file with no result

Tags: selenium, user-input, raw-input

I am playing around with Selenium to get screenshots of websites to view them safely.

The original code I found and tweaked was like this and works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
br = webdriver.PhantomJS()
br.get('http://www.google.com')
br.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
br.quit
```

It gives you a screenshot of the website

I wanted to get user input so that I did not have the VI the file overtime I need a screenshot of a URL this is what I changed the code too.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
br = webdriver.PhantomJS()
br.get_user_input =raw_input('Enter URL:')
br.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
br.quit
```

Now it ask for the URL and you input it in the program runs and finishes and even creates the screenshot.png file but its blank

Comment: ok so I was able to get it working with help from a person I work with she is awesome here is the fix                                                                                #!/usr/bin/python
    import re
    import sys
    from selenium import webdriver
    br = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    user_input =raw_input('Enter URL: ')                                                                              br.get(user_input)
    br.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
br.quit

Answer (score 0):

try to use a chrome canary (if you need headless browser). you don't have to use a selenium.

```
make_screen = '''#!/usr/bin/env bash
    test -f ./chrome-linux/chrome && echo "chrome exists" || unzip chrome-linux.zip
    ./chrome-linux/chrome --headless --disable-gpu --virtual-time-budget=7000 --hide-scrollbars --screenshot=dir/screens/{screen_prod}.png --window-size=1200,2000 {link_prod}'''.format(screen_prod = screen_prod, link_prod = link_prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

There is a small bug in your code. You havn't called the `get()` method with your **`WebDriver`** instance **`br`**.

As a solution, (to avoid [**`Law of Demeter`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)) I have broken up that line in to two. Took the `url` from the user as an input in the first line. In the next line passed the `url` as an argument to `get()` method. Next it takes a proper snapshot and saves it within `Screenshots` sub-directory. Here is the working code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
br = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe")
user_input = input('Enter URL : ')
br.get(str(user_input))
br.save_screenshot('./Screenshots/my_next_screenshot.png')
br.quit
```

The output on my console is:

```
Enter URL : http://google.com
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.